# Finding the corrdinates between points in a meshgrid

Tags: python, numpy

Say that I have a simple meshgrid:

```
xx,yy = np.meshgrid(10,10)
```

and two data points within that meshgrid, e.g. (2,3) and (8,8). What's the easiest way to get an array of all the points in the meshgrid between the two data points forming the shortest distance (i.e. approximating a straight line within the meshgrid)?

Comment: so you would like to sample points from a straight line drawn between (2,3) and (8,8)?

Comment: What are "all points" in this task? Those that are already on the meshgrid? An interpolation? If the latter, what would be the sampling rate? And what have you tried, why did it fail?

Comment: Yes, such that I get an array of the points from the meshgrid that connects the two points with the shortest distance possible

Comment: @Mr.T Interpolation will not necessarily use the exact meshgrid points, but create new data in between the meshes.

Comment: @BallpointBen Almost, the problem is exactly the same, but I do not have a matrix containing only zeros or any other fixed constant

Comment: @kenny The solution generates two arrays of coordinates (`x` and `y`) and only writes to those indices at the very end. You should be able to use that answer pretty much as is.

Answer (score 0):

Check this, you can also control tolerance value

```py
import numpy as np

xx, yy = np.meshgrid(range(1, 11), range(1, 11))
# points
p1 = [2, 3]
p2 = [8, 8]
# slope
m = (p2[1] - p1[1])/(p2[0] - p1[0])

# 2D line equation
through_line = (yy - m*xx) - (p1[1] - m*p1[0])

# to get only the exact points
mask = np.isclose(through_line, 0)
print(list(zip(xx[mask], yy[mask])))

# to get approximate points
tol = 0.2
mask = np.less(np.abs(through_line), tol)
print(list(zip(xx[mask], yy[mask])))
```

```
[(2, 3), (8, 8)]
[(1, 2), (2, 3), (3, 4), (7, 7), (8, 8), (9, 9)]
```

Comment: this creates a line that extend beyond the points p1 and p2. How could I edit the code such that it only gives me the points in between and including p1 and p2?

Comment: you could filter the points based on thresholds of your 2 points. Get the minima of both x and y coordinates of your two points and filter all valid points to have greater than or equal to these minima values and repeat the same with maxima of x and y coordinates to filter valid points, this time with lesser than or equal to condition